# Getting Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 node.js : odoo-xmlrpc

Tags: node.js, npm, meanjs

I am trying to connect to odoo via [odoo-xmlrpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odoo-xmlrpc)

```
var odoo = new Odoo({
  url: 'x.y.z.com',
  port: 80,
  db: 'Data_Base',
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password'
});
```

my debugger shows "client normal" for the second line (console.log(err)) of the code below

```
odoo.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
  console.log('Connected to Odoo server.');
});
```

and this Error for the 3rd line :

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80 }
```

I am using meanjs 0.5.0, this is the development configuration

```
  port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
  host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
```

I tried to use the same code on loopbackjs and it worked, but i need to deploy my app on meanjs why am I getting this error ?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to localhost:80 or x.y.z.com:80?

Comment: not trying to connect to localhost that's the issue i have my own host on port 80

Comment: @AnouarKacem Just execute `netstat -aon | findstr :80` in your command line and see if the port is already in use or not.

Comment: @DavidR as I said x.y.z.com is hosted on a server and port 80 is already free on my local machine

Comment: Were you able to login to your `oodo` online version with your `username` and `password` which you have configured?

Comment: @DavidR yes sure first thing I checked but why it working on loopbackjs and not meanjs with same configs and code ...

Comment: @DavidR I was using odoo-xmlrpc 1.0.5 on loopback and 1.0.6 on meanjs when I downgraded to 1.0.5 on meanjs it worked a short term solution until they solve the issue. thank you for passing by :)

Comment: Great!.. Kindly update your question with this interim solution, someone might get benefited out in feature.

Comment: @DavidR done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using odoo-xmlrpc 1.0.5 on loopbackjs and 1.0.6 on meanjs ... When I downgraded to to 1.0.5 it worked on meanjs and to be sure about that i upgraded the package on loopback and i had the same error ...

so it is a version issue at the moment.
thank you for passing by.

**EDIT :**

Must use http://url or https://url